# vHost Apache with Vagrant (ubuntu/trusty64) loads the same project

Tags: php, apache, vagrant, virtualhost

I have this vhost configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin my@email.com
        ServerName local.startup.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/start

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/acces.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/start>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin my@email.com
        ServerName local2.startup.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/start2

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/acces.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/start2>
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The vHost works fine but only for the first one. 
When i go to local2.startup.com its loading the index of local.startup.com ( The first one )

In my /etc/hosts file i have the following line :

```
192.168.33.10   local.startup.com local2.startup.com
```

Here is my vagrant configuration :

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 4567
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.33.10"
end
```

Provision script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Update Ubuntu
apt-get update

echo "----- Provision: Installing Apache..."
apt-get install -y apache2 apache2-utils
a2enmod rewrite
a2dissite 000-default.conf

echo "------ Provision: Setup var/www to point to /vagrant"
rm -rf /var/www
ln -fs /vagrant /var/www

echo "------- Provision: Install Host File"
cp /vagrant/hostfile /etc/apache2/sites-available/project.conf
a2ensite project.conf

apt-get -y autoremove

echo "------Provision: Restarting Apache..."
service apache2 restart
```

Any ideas why its loading the local.start.com index on the other vHost too?

Thanks!

Comment: I may be wrong here but try putting your `DocumentRoot` path in `"` ie `DocumentRoot "/var/www/start2"`

Comment: in addition try the same here `<Directory "/var/www/start2">`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it turns out i needed to provision with the reload command. "vagrant reload --provision" instead of only "vagrant provision"

Comment: you can also remove the `forward_port` since you're using a private IP, you can directly access the IP on port 80